# locate all nested war/jar files inside jboss/wildfly - log4j

Tags: jboss, find, log4j, wildfly

I want to detect all nested wars and jars containing the log4j library. I have jboss/wildfly services. I started to find out with 'locate | grep', but it shows me only tmp directories, not exactly war/jar files, for example :
wildfly-8.0.1.Final/standalone/tmp/vfs/deployment/deployment**.jar

But I want to detect war/jar files.

Does anyone have a solution for that?

Comment: No, it's about checking the package manager to list if there is a log4j package. But I found a way to find out if there are wars/jars including log4j lib by listing war/jar files : 

find /opt/wildfly1/ ! -type d -name \*.jar -exec sh -c 'printf "\n\nFile: {}  /n"; unzip -l {}' ";" | grep -v tmp | egrep 'nArchive|log4j'

find /opt/wildfly1/ ! -type d -name \*.war -exec sh -c 'printf "\n\nFile: {}  /n"; unzip -l {}' ";" | grep -v tmp | egrep 'war|log4j'

Comment: locate just as currently as you used updatedb, but it only runs the same like you remember that you should use -i for grep due case sensitive usage by default